# Recover the number of files imported during a multiple import

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I need to import several files thanks to the technique:

https://gist.github.com/stephlocke/c3299992ef3ac3efe1f978bd1cb0b4b2

I would like to retrieve the information of the number of files imported by the user. It is available somewhere because in the import tool, I can read "X files imported".

But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the files are uploaded (with `fileInput("csvs", ....)`), the paths of these files are located in `input$csvs$datapath`. Then the number of files is `length(input$csvs$datapath)`.

See `?fileInput` for more info about the contents of`input$csvs`.